# How to use multiple if-conditions when applying a lambda function to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nlp

I have a pandas dataframe where each row represents a resume, similar to:

| resume_id | resume_text | color_1 | color 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jane doe skills java driven ... | orange | red |
| 2 | john doe management excel... | red | green |

There is an id column, a preprocessed string column with the text of the resume, and 2 columns classifying the applicant's personality (coming from a personality test).

Now, I defined a function that randomly adds an X number of key words to the resume text. However, each color has a different associated list (list containing of typical key words for those personalities) to pull words from:

```
import random

def addKeyWords(string, color_list):
    resume_word_count = len(string.split())
    percentage = 0.05 # Percentage of total words that needs to be added
    number_of_words_to_be_added = round(int(resume_word_count * percentage))
    list_of_words = random.choices(color_list, k=number_of_words_to_be_added)
    new_string = string + " " + " ".join(list_of_words)
    return new_string
```

Now I want to loop through all the rows of the dataframe and apply the function based on the values of color_1 OR color_2.

For example, if either color_1 or color_2 == "orange" then apply the function such as:

```
df["resume_text_extra"] = df["resume_text"].apply(lambda x: addKeyWords(x, list_orange))
```

However, I can't get it to work with if-else statements within lambda. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you must provide a fully reproducible example will all required data and the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Below example code, using **np.where**. It applies **lambda function** based on the column value

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4]})

df['col2'] = np.where(df['col1']<=2, df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x * 2),
              np.where( df['col1'] == 3, df['col1'],
                       df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x * 4)
              ))

df
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```py
condition = (df['color_1'] == 'orange') | (df['color_2'] == 'orange')
df[condition] = df[condition].apply(lambda x: addKeyWords(x, list_orange))
```